# Connecting Norm to Spectral radius for convergent matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

If a matrix $A$ has spectral radius <1 it is similar to $B$ which has norm <1, using Lyapunov theory. Is there a more precise connection, ie, can we bound spectral radius of $A$ using singular values of $B$?

Here $B=P^{-\frac{1}{2}} A P^\frac{1}{2}$ where $P$ is the solution to Discrete Lyapunov Equation $APA^T-X=-I$, example $A$ and $B$:

[image] [image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-norm-vs-radius.nb)

Comment: @user1551 yes, it's an upper bound. Also it appears that eigenvalues of $A$ are equal to eigenvalues of $B$. Also, I'm seeing on random matrices that the number of eigenvalues of $A$ larger than 1 in magnitude is the same as the number of singular values of $B$ larger than 1 in magnitude

Comment: @user1551 there's a lot more large singular values in random $A$, but $B$ appears to have as many singular values >1 as $A$ has eigenvalues >1 where $B$ is obtained using similarity transformation in the post, [example](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-norm-vs-radius-example.nb) with 2 divergent eigenvalues/singular values, curious why that is

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. You seem to allow $\rho(A)\ge1$ in your linked example. But then the solution $P$ is not necessarily positive definite (or does not even exist). E.g. when $A=2I_2$, the solution $P=-\frac13I_2$ is negative definite. What do you mean by $P^{1/2}$ in this case? However, if you require $\rho(A)<1$, then $P$ is positive definite and $P^{-1/2}(APA^H-P)P^{-1/2}=-P^{-1}$, i.e., $BB^H=I-P^{-1}$. Hence $\|B\|_2$ is necessarily less than $1$.

Comment: OK, the second part may be an artifact of my random matrices being small enough that $P$ is positive definite. For the original question, I was wondering there's a way to bound norm by spectral radius. If spectral radius of $A$ is significantly less than 1, does it tell us that norm of $B$ significantly less than 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering there's a way to bound norm by spectral radius. If spectral radius of $A$ is significantly less than 1, does it tell us that norm of $B$ significantly less than 1?

$\|B\|_2$ can be arbitrarily close to $1$ even if $\rho(A)\ll 1$. In a very extreme example, suppose $A=\pmatrix{0&a\\ 0&0}$, so that $\rho(A)=0$. The unique solution $P$ to the equation $APA^T-P=-I$ is given by $P=\pmatrix{a^2+1&0\\ 0&1}$. Now, from $APA^T-P=-I$, we obtain $P^{-1/2}(APA^T-P)P^{-1/2}=-P^{-1}$, i.e., $BB^T=I-P^{-1}$. Therefore $\|B\|_2=\rho(I-P^{-1})^{1/2}=\big(1-\|P\|_2^{-1}\big)^{1/2}=\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{a^2+1}}$. When $a$ is sufficiently large, $\|B\|_2$ is close to $1$.

In the example above, $\|A\|_2=a$ is large. If you can keep $\|A\|_2$ small, then $\|B\|_2$ is also small. In fact, when $\|A\|_2<1$, the solution to the discrete Lyapunov equation is given by the Neumann series of $A\otimes A$, i.e., $P=\sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k(A^k)^T$. Hence $\|P\|_2\le\big(1-\|A\|_2^2\big)^{-1}$ and
$
\|B\|_2
=\big(1-\|P\|_2^{-1}\big)^{1/2}
\le\|A\|_2.
$